# What View Component does the Google Plus App (Stream) use?

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android

if you use the Google Plus App on Android and switch to the Stream, you get a view where you can swipe to the left and right between the All circles/Incoming/Nearby-Stream. What view component is used for this? Is this a standard Android component? Or where can I find democode how i can build such a view component?

Answer (score 10):

You should take a look at the `ViewPager` from Android Compatibility Package for the desired widget/swipe navigation. Find more about it here 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Also, checkout this recently posted tutorial and some sample code on `ViewPager` by Richard:
http://geekyouup.blogspot.com/2011/07/viewpager-example-from-paug.html

Comment: I think this is the answer you're looking for. Coupling `ViewPager` with `ListView` (which is what they're using for their list) is going to give you something very similar.

Answer (score 1):

It is a combination of a `ViewPager` together with an indicator for where you are currently and where you can go swiping left and right.

A sample of how this can be done along with code you can use in your own apps may for example be found [here](http://www.zylinc.com/blog-reader/items/viewpager-page-indicator.html). I've played with this code a little and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

None of the default widgets/views. I guess, it's some kind of a custom view with swipe functionality.

Honeycomb opens up a few new widgets which seem to have these functionality. Have a look here.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0.html (New Widgets)

Answer (score 0):

I used [APKTool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to take a look at what's going on. Hopefully it is okay to post this here. This is from version 1.0.2 of the G+ APK.

**removed google+ app code as per CommonsWare's suggestion**

So, it looks like they're using standard views, though perhaps with a good deal of gesture detection and smooth animation magic.

EDIT) If you really want to know about the exact inner-workings of what is going on in the Stream activity, I suggest you use APKTool yourself and examine the .smali code

Comment: "Hopefully it is okay to post this here." -- posting code in violation of its copyright and license is not "okay".

Comment: I'm not trying to defend this post, and I'm far from being knowledgeable about copyright law, but I wasn't able to find anything that constitutes the G+ app's "copyright and license". Clearly it isn't open source. Feel free to inform me.

Comment: Google is US-based firm; all works created in the US are automatically copyrighted (with a few exceptions, such as works created by federal government employees). Hence, unless you have an explicit license to copy it, you do not have the rights to copy it. So, for example, if the G+ app were demonstrably open source, including code snippets from it here would be perfectly delightful.